# Is IntelliJ's java singleton thread-safe

Tags: java

IntelliJ can autogenerate a template for a singleton class, which looks something like this:

```
public class A {
    private static A ourInstance = new A();

    public static A getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private A() {
    }
}
```

Is this implementation of singleton thread-safe? I have read about implementing thread-safe singletons through enums. I was wondering if the above implementation is thread-safe as well. As 'ourInstance' has been defined as static and initialized as a class variable, there should be just one copy of the object.

Comment: It's published safely, yes. But make the field `final` for good practice.

Comment: you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `final` to your `static` variable `ourInstance` to prevent any later modifications then you will have a perfect thread safe `singleton`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this implementation is thread-safe. Static fields are guaranteed to be initialised and visible before this class or any instance of it are available to the rest of java code.